# Summary of types of equivalence and equality in type theory, with notations and examples

Tags: reference-request, type-theory, equality, c++

Coming from non-computer science background, I am trying to understand the different types of equivalence and equality usually used in type theory. Ideally, I am looking for clear **definitions** and **notations** (ie the symbols commonly used) of:

- difference between equivalence and equality of types $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$
- definitional equivalence(/equality?) of types $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$
- structural equivalence(/equality?) of types $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$
- observational equivalence(/equality?) of types $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$
- denotational equivalence(/equality?) of types $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$
- [other] equivalence(/equality?) of types $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$
- etc...

**Illustrations** of the different types of equivalence/equality in a common programming language (ideally C++) would also really help.

Comment: The terminology varies and so it's difficult to give you a good answer, unless you tell us what your sources were. *Where* did you see these terms used, specifically? For example, "boservational equivalence" can mean several things, and so can "equivalence".

Comment: @Vincent You're also not likely to see good examples of these in C++, because many of these are concepts that specifically apply to dependently-typed languages, which C++ is not.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I could not really pinpoint where I saw each of these, I just know I've seen them in type theory books. If you have the knowledge to answer the question from the standpoint of a particular domain/community/author, that would already be a big help. I posted this question a while ago and back at that time, I was reading books on type theory and HoTT. (and you can forget the illustration part, I think I've read enough on type theory now to be able to interpret your answer).